# Run-time of Sorting Algorithm

Tags: runtime-analysis, sorting

**Problem**

Consider the pseudocode for the `sort` algorithm below, which takes as input an unsorted array $A$ of $n$ integers with no duplicates.

```
sort(A, i, j)
  if i = j
    return
  m = floor[(i + j)/2]
  sort(A, i, m)
  sort(A, m + 1, j)
  if A[m] > A[j]
    swap A[m] and A[j]
  sort(A, i, j - 1)
```

Write a recurrence that characterizes the runtime of sort(A, 0, n-1).

**Attempted Solution**

Let $T(n)$ be the run-time of `sort(A, 0, n-1)`

`if i = j then return` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} O\hspace{0.01cm}(1)$

`m = floor[(i + j)/2]` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} O\hspace{0.01cm}(1)$

`sort(A, i, m)` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} T(\frac{n}{2})$

`sort(A, m + 1, j)` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} T(\frac{n}{2})$

`if A[m] > A[j] then swap A[m] and A[j]` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} O\hspace{0.01cm}(1)$

`sort(A, i, j - 1)` $\hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} T(n - 1)$

$\therefore T(n) \hspace{0.1cm} = \hspace{0.1cm} 2 \hspace{0.1cm} T(\frac{n}{2}) \hspace{0.1cm} + \hspace{0.1cm} T(n - 1) + \hspace{0.1cm} O\hspace{0.01cm}(1)$

Is this correct? Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

**Sort in Action**

The `sort` algorithm actually works. See this example to convince yourself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/27d8g.jpg

Comment: does this really sorts?

Comment: Yes it does. But that is besides the point here, I need a recurrence.

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I posted a pic where I compiled this algorithm with a test case - it actually sorted!

Comment: Yes, I looked again and saw that, apart from exercise, no use.

Answer (score 1):

This is just Bubble-Sort in disguise. Each time, you get the biggest element pushed to the end of the array, then you sort the remaining of the array.

Your recurrence is correct.

An upper bound would be $T(n) = O(2^n)$.

Proof: For large enough $n$, we have $T(n)\leq 2^n$. This is the base case for induction. Induction hypothesis is $T(n)\leq 2^n$. So, we have $$2\sqrt{2^n}+\frac{2^n}2+O(1)\leq 2^n$$.